# Perl not able to access sub from module file

Tags: perl, module, perl-module

I have create two files both in same folder to learn modules.

Modules.pm

```
package Modules;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

BEGIN { our @EXPORT = qw(Print); }

sub Print { print shift(@_); }

END { }

1;
```

Main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Modules;

Print("Hello World!");
```

on running the command perl Main.pl I'm getting the following error. What I am doing wrong?

```
Undefined subroutine &main::Print called at Main.pl line 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgot to tell your package that it inherits from `Exporter`

```
package Modules;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(Print);

sub Print { print shift(@_); }


1;
```

or less error prone,

```
package Modules;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent qw( Exporter );
our @EXPORT = qw(Print);

sub Print { print shift(@_); }


1;
```

More in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)

Comment: In practice, manual modification of `@ISA` should be avoided. `use parent 'Exporter'` will take care of loading and inheriting from Exporter.